# How to deny internet permission to Android IME input method service from application manifest

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, ime

In an Android application that defines a input method service, is it possible to deny internet permission for the service, but request internet access for other activities in the application?   In my tests I couldn't find a way to do this.  Here is an example manifest file that defines the IME and also a main activity for the application.   I would like to allow internet permission for the main activity, but deny internet permission the IME "MyKeyboard".    Is it possible on Android?  It is possible in iOS.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mykeyboard" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application>

    <service android:name="com.example.mykeyboard.MyKeyboard"
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>

    <activity android:name="com.example.mykeyboard.MainActivity"
              android:label="My Keyboard" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```